# My ubuntu 18.0.4 will not create a "matlab" file from installation

Tags: matlab

So I installed Matlab from their site. I got the latest Linux .zip file, `MCR_R2018a_glnxa64_installer.zip`, unzipped it via `unzip` and ran install.

It worked, I got the different paths at the end as well. However, the command `matlab` wouldn't work. I tried to look for the file at the install location, at `/usr/local/...`

Then I tried to find the file by using the `find` command. I ran `(sudo) find / -name "matlab"` and `(sudo) find / -type f -name "matlab"`. The first one gave me a whole list, so I check a few and they were just directories, so I switched it to the second command listed and got nothing. No output.

Did I do something wrong? Is there anything I can try?

Comment: You should probably ask this question on http://superuser.com or http://askubuntu.com .

Comment: You need to create a symbolic link.  MATLAB installation usually gives a by-default unchecked option of creating symbolic links which you apparently kept unchecked during your installation. But it is doable after the installation as well. See: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96149